# Network cable not working - dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ubuntu

I have dual boot (Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10) installed on my laptop.

I found out, that when I shut down Ubuntu and run Windows then often happens that network cable stops working. I usually restart the laptop then and then it starts working (sometimes two restarts are needed) or I disconnect cable, shut down Ubuntu, run Windows and connect cable.

I know that earplugs do not have to work when you are on Ubuntu and then restart and run Windows (if you shut down Ubuntu and run Windows, they are OK). So I think that this may be similar problem.

Does anyone experienced it too? Some fixes?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the problem once and i fixed it via the following link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/846125/ubuntu-dual-boot-windows-ethernet-not-connecting-detecting

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem.
I've found this forum post:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1469623&p=9746030#post9746030

> Anyway, it seems the fix is to plug your computer out of the socket for a couple of minutes, there's a long thread (with solutions) about
> the exact problem here:
> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1436667&page=1
>
> Short version: Ubuntu loads firmware for the wrong chipset onto the
> card, which can only be cleared with loss of electricity for a few
> minutes. It worked for me. Still a pretty horribly bug on Ubuntu devs
> part.

That answer is from 2010 though, but it could be it. In my case, plugging the PC off and waiting and then booting Windows solves the Ethernet problem. But of course, that's not how it's supposed to work. I haven't yet read the full thread in that reply for any actual solutions (that don't require waiting and unplugging), but please edit this answer to include them or post another answer, if you find those.